# How to sending api payload content to bam

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-bam

I'm using Api Manager Version 1.7.0 and BAM Version 4.2.0: installing API_Manager_Analytics toolbox I have any field values predefined (e.g payload_api, payload_apiPublisher etc...); For the requests I see them in Cassandra DB under EVENT_KS org_wso2_apimgt_statistics_request: how do I get the field values of the requests used to invoke the apis in org_wso2_apimgt_statistics_request? how do I pass the soap body payload content to BAM? Tks Gius

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please show what you have coded so far for context.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you can write custom data publisher as mentioned here[1] or you can use bam mediator[2] and publish in to separate stream

1.https://nadeesha678.wordpress.com/2015/12/14/how-to-publish-custom-set-of-data-from-api-manager-to-wso2-business-activity-monitor/
2.https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/BAM+Mediator